# How to facet/histogram the following in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have the following fields:

```
timestamp: (elasticsearch date field)
ice-cream-flavor: (e.g. Chocolate, Vanilla, Strawberry)
container: (e.g. Cup, Cone)
```

I want to be able to use some kind of facet to be able to give me a count based on:

```
timestamp: (bucketed by day)
ice-cream-flavor count (how many Chocolate on that day? How many Vanilla that day?)
```

Could I take it a step further and do:

I want to be able to use some kind of facet to be able to give me a count based on:

```
timestamp: (bucketed by day)
ice-cream-flavor count (how many Chocolate on that day? How many Vanilla that day?)
container count (based on time bucketed by day, could I get the count of how many of each ice cream flavor were stored in a container?)
```

Is this possible? What kind of facet is this? Could you provide an example? I tried using the DateHistogram and Histogram facet but it appears that if I specify the field to be a date, I get some random key with some random count that makes no sense....

What I've tried...
Given a date histogram with a specified "field=timestamp", I get the following output that appears to make no sense. It expects a key field and a value field with a value field that has to be an integer? It doesnt make much sense... and does not take into account the specific conditions I want.

```
myhistogram: {
_type: "date_histogram",
entries: [
{},
{
count: 1,
time: 634579946870400000
},
{
count: 1,
time: 634580073100800000
}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date histogram supports a "value_field" parameter for bucketing, but it only supports numeric values.
There is a plugin [elasticfacets](https://github.com/bleskes/elasticfacets) which seems to allow using the date histogram facet with any other facet to bucket on.